# Listen Dialog Positive button click in each ViewPager fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-dialogfragment

I'm testing a function of listening the `AlertDialog` button click (Positive & Neutral) in each `ViewPager` fragment. And I am using the `Interface` method right now but getting some troubles.

So the structure is like this, I have an `AlertDialog` created by `DialogFragment`, and I put a `ViewPager` with two fragments into this `DialogFragment`. My goal is, when I click on the Positive button on the `AlertDialog`, I want some methods inside those two `ViewPager` fragments get called so that I can collect the data on those fragments.

Now the problem is, only the second fragment responses, I don't know why.

Here are the codes:

1. I created an Interface file

   ```
   public interface Communicator {
       void onConfirmClick();
   }
   ```
2. I have a DialogFragment

   ```
   public class MainDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
       View dialogLayout;
       Communicator communicator;

       @Override
       public void onAttachFragment(Fragment childFragment) {
           communicator = (Communicator) childFragment;
       }

       @Nullable
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           return dialogLayout;
       }

       @NonNull
       @Override
       public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
           dialogLayout = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_main, null);
           ViewPager viewPager = dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.main_viewPager);

           final MainPagerAdapter adapter = new MainPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
           viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

           dialogBuilder.setView(dialogLayout);
           dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", null);
           dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
           dialogBuilder.setNeutralButton("Change", null);

           final AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();

           dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
               @Override
               public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                   dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View view) {
                           communicator.onConfirmClick();
                       }
                   });

           dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View view) {
                           Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Change click!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   });
               }
           });

           return dialog;
       }
   }
   ```
3. My fragment A

   ```
   public class MainFragmentA extends Fragment implements Communicator{
       View rootView;

       @Nullable
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

           return rootView;
       }

       @Override
       public void onConfirmClick() {
           Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fragment A!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }
   ```
4. My fragment B

   ```
   public class MainFragmentB extends Fragment implements Communicator{
       View rootView;

       @Nullable
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);

           return rootView;
       }

       @Override
       public void onConfirmClick() {
           Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fragment B!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }
   ```
5. My ViewPager adapter used inside DialogFragment

   ```
   public class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
       public MainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
           super(fragmentManager);
       }

       @Override
       public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           switch (position) {
               case 0:
                   return new MainFragmentA();

               case 1:
                   return new MainFragmentB();

               default:
                   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong position!!");
           }
       }

       @Override
       public int getCount() {
           return 2;
       }
   }
   ```
6. My MainActivity

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
       Button showDialogButton;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           showDialogButton = findViewById(R.id.main_show_dialog_button);

           showDialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   MainDialogFragment mainDialogFragment = new MainDialogFragment();
                   mainDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "mainDialogFragment");
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```

Anyone can help? I'll so appreciate that!!!

Comment: Can you please post the code from the fragments loaded into `ViewPager` which is handling the click?

Comment: @Reaz Murshed Hi, I have uploaded all my code, please check.

Comment: Thanks and good to see that you have formatted your code and the question quite nicely. Kudos! Please check my answer below. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `collection` of some sort of `Communicator` interfaces instead of a single one. You're overwriting the `communicator` every time a child fragment is attached.

```
public class MainDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    View dialogLayout;
    List<Communicator> communicators = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment childFragment) {
        communicators.add((Communicator) childFragment);
    }

    // all the other things from the MainDialogFragment...
}
```

And in the `BUTTON_POSITIVE` callback iterate through the list.

```
dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        for (Communicator communicator : communicators) { 
            communicator.onConfirmClick();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You are my lifesaver!! Thank you soooooooooo much!!

Answer (score 1):

> Only the communicator from the second fragment works

This is because you have two different instances of communicator in each of your fragments. As you are setting up the `ViewPager`, the second fragment is the last one that is being attached with the parent fragment. Hence, the `communicator` that you are initializing inside the `onAttachFragment` function of your `MainDialogFragment` class, is storing the reference from the second fragment only as this was the last one to be attached here.

In your case, I would rather suggest a very simple implementation using the lifecycle functions of the `Fragment`. Just take a `public static` variable in your `MainDialogFragment` class which will indicate if the okay button was clicked or not. And then check the value of that variable from each of your `Fragment` class inside the `onResume` function and perform the tasks accordingly. To get an idea of the implementation, please check the following.

Get a variable in your `MainDialogFragment` class like the following.

```
public static boolean isDialogOkayClicked = false; // Default false
```

Now in your `MainFragmentA`, implement the `onResume` function and check the value from the `MainDialogFragment`. Take the actions accordingly.

```
public class MainFragmentA extends Fragment implements Communicator{
    View rootView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(MainDialogFragment.isDialogOkayClicked) 
            doSomething();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfirmClick() {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fragment A!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Do the same thing for your other fragment.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, but I prefer the first answer, it's easier and more straight to me.